# Implementation of clock()

Tags: linux, time, clock

I was going through stackoverflow threads on various mechanisms for computing CPU time of a process.

How is `clock()` internally implemented ? Does it use `rdtsc()` ( If that's the case then it is sensitive to migration between cores ).

Also, `getrusage()` implemented ? Does it also depend on TSC ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The kernel keeps track of CPU utilization for processes in sizes of ticks.

Both `clock()` and `getrusage()` are both based on these.

Ticks are accumulated by processes by the kernel using a sampling method in which the kernel receives a hardware interrupt for the clock and executes the clock handler, which adds the tick to the currently running process.  At least, this is how it worked last time I looked.

So, `rtdsc` does not come into play at all - which is a good thing since `rdtsc` does not measure accurately across CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily glance at some libc code. Here is the [time/](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/time) directory of `musl-libc`

On several libraries, some low level timing syscalls are using [VDSO](http://lwn.net/Articles/342018/) to avoid paying the cost of a real syscall (from user-space to kernel and back), so somehow uses RTDSC.

But I am surprised that you ask. If it is curiosity, just study the source code of free software implementation. Otherwise, trust the specifications & the implementations.

<sup>Gory details could be complex, since implementation and system specific. The real implementation could be dynamically tuned at run-time (eg thru VDSO set-up in the kernel).</sup>